# MySQL stored procedure with parameters and variables error

Tags: mysql

I'm getting a syntax error although I've followed this tutorial http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,358569 .. Something is missing and I can't figure out what it is. the error message says it is in line 1. I've checked this line over and over I don't see where the problem is.

```
DELIMITER $$
create or replace procedure profile_fullname(IN memid number)
begin
declare v_name varchar2(100);
declare fn varchar2(50);
declare ln varchar2(50);


select fname, lname into fn, ln from member where memberid = memid;
v_name := fn || ' ' || ln;

insert into profile(memberid, fullName) values (memid, v_name);

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

the error message #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'procedure profile_fullname(IN memid number) begin declare v_name varchar2(100)' at line 1

Comment: what is the actual error ?

Comment: `DELIMITER $$ ` and then start the stored procedure as you have not started that is why it's giving error at line `1`

Comment: do you have the DELIMITER at the very beginning like : DELIMITER $$  then  create or replace procedure profile_fullname

Comment: yes I have my delimiter @user3470953 it says syntax error in line 1

Comment: @NaveedYousaf I have my delimiter $$

Comment: @Wabbit give the detailed error in your question which will help us to give you proper answer

Comment: oh never mind, I figured it out eventually.. o,o The problem was in using varchar2 as a datatype for the variables. I changed it to varchar and it worked now. Thanks anyway guys.

Comment: does MySQL have data type number ? I think MySQL does not have data type number. you can have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-types.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of errors in your code:

Use `DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS profile_fullname;` instead of `or replace`, which can only be used with views.

Replace `number` in  `profile_fullname(IN memid number)` with `INT` or whatever you need. There's no `number` type in MySQL.

Replace all `varchar2` with `VARCHAR`. Looks like you're mixing things up with Oracle. There's also no `varchar2` type.

Replace `v_name := fn || ' ' || ln;` with `SET v_name := fn || ' ' || ln;`. You have to set a variable using the keyword `SET`.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS profile_fullname;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE profile_fullname(IN memid INT)

BEGIN

DECLARE v_name VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE fn VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE ln VARCHAR(50);

SELECT fname, lname into fn, ln
    FROM member
    WHERE memberid = memid;

SET v_name := fn || ' ' || ln;

INSERT INTO profile (memberid, fullName)
    VALUES (memid, v_name);

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
create or alter procedure profile_fullname(IN memid number)
```

instead of,

```
create or replace procedure profile_fullname(IN memid number)
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Even if this was the only error in his code, your code wouldn't work. There's no `CREATE OR ALTER` clause in MySQL, afaik. The `CREATE OR REPLACE` clause used by @Wabbit does exit, but can only be applied on views.